# how to ignore content type with golang?

Tags: java, go

can somebody tell me how to ignore content type with go? I can invoke ignoreContentType method in Jsoup with java, but i can't find any method in go can do like that. Hope someone will tell me, thanks.

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/")
            .ignoreContentType(true)
            .execute();
System.out.println(response.body());
```

Comment: Why are you trying to ignore the Content-Type? Is the Content-Type causing you an issue in code? And if yes, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: nothing error returns, i will post another comment to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem after read Jsoup's source code, just set the response header

```
resp.Header.Set("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked")
resp.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

thanks you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Java [jsoup `ignoreContentType`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#ignoreContentType-boolean-) is there to ignore the document's `Content-Type` when parsing the response.

The [`ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) in Go will by default adds a Content-Type set to the result of passing the initial 512 bytes of written data to `DetectContentType`.

You can implement your own `ResponseWriter` where you set your own `Content-Type` to `""` in order to ignore any (possibly incorrect) content type deduced from the Response's data.

```
func (writer MyOwnResponseWriter) Write(data []byte) (int, error) {
    writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", "")
    return len(data), nil
}
```

[JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41375662/how-to-ignore-content-type-with-golang/41376212?noredirect=1#comment69967195_41376212) to simply set your own Content-Type, as [`server.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9719ca9c0e6fdda273cd178e6cce6b88d738518e/src/net/http/server.go#L115-L119) includes:

```
//If the Header does not contain a Content-Type line, 
// Write adds a Content-Type set to the result of 
// passing the initial 512 bytes of written data toDetectContentType.
```

Comment: You can also just set the Content-Type header -- the go http server won't try to detect and overwrite it if it's there already.

Comment: @JimB I would have thought the go http server could make its own Response, with its own header depending on how said http server is implemented.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but the headers set in the `ReponseWriter` take precedence up until `WriteHeader` is called. If you look for `DetectContentType` in the server.go source, you can see that it first checks if the `Content-Type` header has been set.

Comment: @JimB OK. I see now.